# Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index in datagridview VB .net

Tags: sql, vb.net, datagridview

I have this code

```
    For sc5 = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1

        If (DataGridView5.Item(0, sc5).ToString = 
        DataGridView5.Item(0, sc5 + 1).ToString) And 
        (DataGridView5.Item(4, sc5).ToString = DataGridView5. 
        Item(4, sc5 + 1).ToString) Then

           DataGridView5.Rows.RemoveAt(sc5 + 1)

    End If

Next
```

My problem is it always Show `index was out of range` but i able to set the index at 0.

Answer (score 0):

your problem is when sc5 reaches the last value. the last value is rowCount-1. in your code you are adding 1 to this in a few cases when indexing the data grid. this means at some point your row index will be rowCount. the row indices should go from 0 to rowCount-1 inclusive. you are exceeding this.

Answer (score 0):

If last execution `sc5=datagridview.RowCount-1` that time u check the value of `sc5 + 1`
So that time its show index out of range value

Try Like this

```
  For xi As Integer = DataGridView1.RowCount - 1 To 1 Step -1

            If DataGridView1.Item(0, xi).Value.ToString =
            DataGridView1.Item(0, xi - 1).Value.ToString andalso 
            (DataGridView5.Item(4, xi).ToString = 
            DataGridView5.Item(4, xi-1).ToString)Then

                DataGridView1.Rows.Remove(DataGridView1.Rows(xi))

            End If

  Next
```